# How we can know is an app install correctly?

Tags: apt, software-installation, directory

I am new in ubuntu and I want to install quantum espresso by the following command:

```
apt-get install quantum espresso
```

But I can't find its folder in ubuntu so I can't run it.
What can I do?

Thanks for your replying

Answer (score 1):

You have used incorrect package name. See [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=quantum+espresso&searchon=names) for details.

The correct is the `quantum-espresso` with purpose

> Electronic-Structure and Ab-Initio Molecular Dynamics Suite

You have to install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install quantum-espresso
```

After this you will be able to run one of [its executables](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/quantum-espresso/filelist):

*average.x*, *bands.x*, *bgw2pw.x*, *bse_main.x*, *casino2upf.x*, *cp.x*, *cpmd2upf.x*, *cppp.x*, *dist.x*, *dos.x*, *dynmat.x*, *epsilon.x*, *ev.x*, *fd.x*, *fd_ef.x*, *fd_ifc.x*, *fhi2upf.x*, *fpmd2upf.x*, *fqha.x*, *fs.x*, *generate_rVV10_kernel_table.x*, *generate_vdW_kernel_table.x*, *gww.x*, *gww_fit.x*, *head.x*, *importexport_binary.x*, *initial_state.x*, *interpolate.x*, *iotk.x*, *iotk_print_kinds.x*, *kpoints.x*, *lambda.x*, *ld1.x*, *manycp.x*, *manypw.x*, *matdyn.x*, *molecularnexafs.x*, *molecularpdos.x*, *ncpp2upf.x*, *neb.x*, *oldcp2upf.x*, *path_interpolation.x*, *pawplot.x*, *ph.x*, *phcg.x*, *plan_avg.x*, *plotband.x*, *plotproj.x*, *plotrho.x*, *pmw.x*, *pp.x*, *projwfc.x*, *pw.x*, *pw2bgw.x*, *pw2gw.x*, *pw2wannier90.x*, *pw4gww.x*, *pw_export.x*, *pwcond.x*, *pwi2xsf.x*, *q2qstar.x*, *q2r.x*, *q2trans.x*, *q2trans_fd.x*, *read_upf_tofile.x*, *rrkj2upf.x*, *spectra_correction.x*, *sumpdos.x*, *turbo_davidson.x*, *turbo_eels.x*, *turbo_lanczos.x*, *turbo_spectrum.x*, *upf2casino.x*, *uspp2upf.x*, *vdb2upf.x*, *virtual.x*, *wannier_ham.x*, *wannier_plot.x*, *wfck2r.x*, *wfdd.x*, *xspectra.x*